# Al extraer texto de un PDF con PDFBox me cambia tildes por carácteres raros

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, utf-8, unicode

Tengo este código en java para coger un archivo PDF y extraer todo el texto:

```
File archivo = new File("C:/Archivo.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(archivo);
PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();
contenido= s.getText(document);
System.out.println(contenido);
```

Si ejecutamos la aplicación con windows extrae correctamente todo el texto. Sin embargo, cuando lo pasamos al servidor que usa Linux, los tildes se convierten en carácteres tipo --> carÃ¡cter (tendría que ser carácter).
He intentado de convertir el String a bytes y luego a unicode UTF8:

```
byte[] b = contenido.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
String texto= new String(b);
System.out.println(texto);
```

Pero no funciona, en Windows sigue funcionando bien y en el server Linux sigue mostrando mal los tildes, etc...
Entiendo que si en un entorno windows sale correctamente, en un entorno Linux tendría que poder salir también...
¿Alguna idea de que puede ser o que puedo hacer?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si guardas lo extraido en algun tipo de fichero, desde la consola de linux lanza:
file -bi ejemplo.php
Y mira el charset que usas.

Si directamente es desde un script es porqué tendrás el Linux usando otro tipo de codificación.
Prueba con " locale charmap " desde terminal a ver que te marca.

"Entiendo que si en un entorno windows sale correctamente, en un entorno Linux tendría que poder salir también"
Son So distintos, no tienen porqué mostrar lo mismo, todo depende de como estén configurados.

Comment: Con lo de los entornos me refería a que si el PDF es el mismo y la libreria que uso es la misma (PDFBox), da la sensación que tendría que salir igual, o que no tendría que haber mucho problema.